# Cделать главный layout (main.xml) пролистываемым

Tags: xml, java

Разрабатываю приложение в `Eclipse`, столкнулся с проблемой. Мне нужно сделать главный layout (`main.xml`) пролистываемым. То есть, чтобы при большом количестве элементов на экране его можно было прокручивать пальцем вниз. Для этого я использовал `ScrollView`, но я не могу скомпилировать и запустить программу. Компилятор выдает ошибку в этих строчках:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

Вот сам код:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:background="@drawable/background"
      android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
      android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
      android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
      android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
      android:isScrollContainer="true"
      tools:context=".MainActivity" >

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/textViewPhoneNo"
          android:text="Кому :"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="0dp"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

      <EditText
          android:id="@+id/editTextTo"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="0dp"
          android:inputType="textEmailAddress" >

          <requestFocus />
      </EditText>

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/textViewSubject"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Заголовок :"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

      <EditText
          android:id="@+id/editTextSubject"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="45dp" />

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/textViewMessage"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Ваша история :"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

      <EditText
          android:id="@+id/editTextMessage"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:gravity="top" />

      <Button
          android:id="@+id/buttonSend"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Отправить" />

      <Button 
          android:id="@+id/btnInfo"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="О приложении"
          android:onClick="onclock" />"

      <TextView 
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="@string/message_text"
          android:autoLink="web" />

  </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У Вас не закрыт тег от ScrollView. Вот так правильно:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
```

И лишние кавычки в самом конце тут:

```
  <Button 
      android:id="@+id/btnInfo"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="О приложении"
      android:onClick="onclock" />"
```

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте, не попадают ли [специальные символы разметки](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML#.D0.A1.D0.B8.D0.BC.D0.B2.D0.BE.D0.BB.D1.8B_.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.B7.D0.BC.D0.B5.D1.82.D0.BA.D0.B8._.D0.A0.D0.B5.D1.88.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5_.D0.BF.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B1.D0.BB.D0.B5.D0.BC.D1.8B_.D0.BD.D0.B5.D0.BE.D0.B4.D0.BD.D0.BE.D0.B7.D0.BD.D0.B0.D1.87.D0.BD.D0.BE.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B8_.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.B7.D0.BC.D0.B5.D1.82.D0.BA.D0.B8) в ваши строчки (если присутствует подставляемый контент).

"*Компилятор выдает ошибку в этих строчках...*" - вы ничего не сказали про ошибку, ее описание, зато целый параграф посвятили описанию какой вы программист. Опишите ошибку.